# Sorting Children in Laravel : How do I sort children by name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Below is my controller code

```
$categories = Category::where('parentId', '=', 0)
                                ->with('children')
                                ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                                ->get();    
return view('home', compact('categories'));
```

When I access my categories and its children in the view, the categories seem to be sorted by name but the children categories are not. How do I sort the children categories as well by name?

Also, is it possible to sort the categories using a different criteria than the children eg. By position for categories and name for children. If yes, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to apply **order by** on children, not categories. The following code will do the trick:

```
$categories = Category::whereParentId(0)
  ->with(['children' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
  }])
  ->get();
```

Comment: Also you can find good example here: https://stephen.rees-carter.net/thought/sorting-eager-loaded-records-in-laravels-eloquent

Comment: Helpful, but some typos in the sample code (no ; and no ] ) - but the edit queue is full.

Comment: if someone is wondering from where whereParentId comes from, it is a concatination of where + your-column-name so in this case, it is becoming whereParentId method. Plus, if you are interested to dynamically decide the column name you may use use method next to the function($query) like 

function($query) use($ur-var) and then use the $ur-var inside the query.